# Reducing line height in angular material tree

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using a [angular tree material](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) to display JSON data, I am unsatisfied by the amount of white spacing there is between lines. I have tried playing with `mat-tree-node.line-height` in the css with zero changes. How can I reduce all this vertical white space?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply by overriding their css:

```
.mat-tree-node { min-height: 30px }
```

Comment: Is there a way of setting `max-height` depending on `font-size`, as `1.5x` ? I am very unfamiliar with css and maybe I should ask that somewhere else.

Comment: Yes by typing this: `min-height: 1.5em;` but notice that the left arrow has an height of 40px, so you may also need to reduce his height.

Comment: Indeed, thanks again for the input and the promptness.

Comment: Is it `min-height` or `max-height`?

Comment: it's min-height

Comment: that works but why the nested <li> cannot get 100% of the height? .. it kills me. There's no padding, no margin ..

Answer (score 7):

The only working way I found with **angular 8** on a nested element (and nested tree) is

```
.mat-tree-node {
  min-height: 1.2em !important;
  height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: also seems to work for flat tree

Comment: on a nested tree, you can style the different nodes as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BALaj39rbZE

Comment: This worked for me too on a tree with flat nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
mat-tree-node {
    max-height: 16px
}
```

for Angular 16