# Can't adjust line height of list items in a mat-tree

Tags: css, angular, treeview

I’m working with a mat-tree in my Angular 7 application. It looks like this:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl" class="example-tree">

<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
  <li>
    <span *ngFor="let item of getArrayForIndenting(node)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{ node.name }}: {{ node.value }}
  </li>
</mat-tree-node>

<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
  <div>
    <span *ngFor="let item of getArrayForIndenting(node)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{ nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{ node.name }}
  </div>
  <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
    <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
  </ul>
</mat-nested-tree-node>
```

[image]

Notice that each node is spaced really far apart vertically. This is what I’m trying to adjust.

I’ve tried everything. I’ve tried styling the height of various elements in the above markup, the line-height, the margins, the padding, etc., but nothing works.

According to this site:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ul_compact_css

I should be able to set the line-height on the ul element, but I tried that and it doesn’t work.

Can anyone tell what I’m supposed to do? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the CSS:

```
.example-tree-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.example-tree li,
.example-tree ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Note that I removed the "mat-tree-node" class 'cause it didn't exist.

There's also a reference to fonts.googleapis.com in my index.html file:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

...which is probably what mat-icon-rtl-mirror comes from.

Hope that helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing line height in angular material tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483145/reducing-line-height-in-angular-material-tree)

Answer (score 1):

The only working way I found with **angular 8** on a nested element (and nested tree) is

```
.mat-tree-node {
  min-height: 1.2em !important;
  height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: worked for me on specifying min-height and height both

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right you should be able to set line height of ul or li elements. However, you have not pasted the css for the above code. Please give us css or create https://plnkr.co/
so that we can debug and help you. It is also possible that you may have margin or padding in ul or li element, check that as well.

Comment: I added the CSS in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

just use .css to override min-height, e.g.

```
.mat-tree-node {
    min-height:1.6rem; //min-heigth:0 if you want the min heigth possible
}
```